# Methods for studying quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I want to study quantum mechanics and quantum electrodynamics, chromodynamics after this. Can you please help me with the choice of books, methods of studying the topic (I have a good knowledge of analysis and algebra,know quantum mechanics at a basic level, but I’m rather poorly versed in tensors)